# Html to PDF using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: c#, html, pdf

I am trying to creat my reporting system using html and transforming it into pdf. I am using wkhtmltopdf, and what i have done is creating the report in a url and calling in using wkhtmltopdf, but when url takes to long to load the conversion fails.

Does anyone have experience with converting html to pdf? or is the technology not ready yet?

Comment: no code... i wrote that i tried using wkhtmltopdf, its an exe  that can transform urls into pdf.. i have given it some complex pages in my project and it fails. that's it

Comment: Ok. Did you search for alternative solution? What did you do?

Comment: Yes this post pretty much sums up the options :http://jsreport.net/blog/pdf-reports-in-csharp , if html to pdf won't work i will go with itextsharp, but trml to pdf will make my life much easier

Answer (score 0):

After many problems with other libraries I used mPDF and it worked very good. Download the latest version, read documentation here (http://www.mpdf1.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Although you have moved to different library, I am still answering here so that it can be helpful to other users facing the same issue.

The trick is to use

> javascript-delay

option of wkhtmltopdf where value is given in ms.

eg:

> wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 1000 http://your.url.com pdf_name.pdf